# Crystal report shows Rounded value instead of decimal automatically for if else query

Tags: .net, sql-server-2008

I created a query in sql server which contains if else condition, and use this query to create a report in sap crystal report.

In my query if condition contains a "<" statement. When executing the query i get correct answers (i.e values with decimal points) but when comes to the report it shows rounded value. And most confusing fact is that if the query enters in "if" clause first then the report shows rounded value, but not for else condition (i.e if the query enters first in else condition the report shows
decimal values).

In second attempt i put "<=" in "if" condition. This time the report shows Rounded value for else part and decimal value for if part. (There is no loop in my query so it enters if or else condition only once). I want Decimal value for both if and else clause. What should i do?

Query:

```
if(var1<var2) //both variables are in float
begin
   select sum(Column1 in float datatype) as Column1 
end
else
begin
   select sum(Column2 in float datatype) as Column2 
end
```

On executing the query it results as 22567.91 as column 1, but in report it shows as 22568, in another attempt on executing the query it results as 5734.51 as column 2, the report shows 5734.51.

I want Decimal values at both attempt.

Answer (score 0):

select 
case when (var1
when (var1>var2)
 then   sum(salary2 ) 
end

from test
group by var1,var2

-- You can use case .. I tried your same query in sql its working fine. If its not showing in crystal report then you can set property for decimal.